# Changing a SQL statement when columns have been extracted to a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We have a database that keeps track of Client issues. I have been tasked with adding a Site tab, and as a part of this, we extracted the address information from the dbo.client table, and created a new dbo.address table.

I am new to SQL, but have managed to muddle my way through modifying the Stored Procedures. However, we have one method that creates a dynamic SQL statement, and since it tries to access address information from the dbo.client table rather than the new dbo.address table, and obviously does not work.

One possible iteration of this statement is below:

```
select iclientid, 
    (select top 1 isstype.cistypdesc 
        from issue 
            inner join status on issue.istatusid = status.istatusid 
            left outer join priorty on issue.ipriortyid = priorty.ipriortyid 
            left outer join isstype on issue.iisstypeid = isstype.iisstypeid 
        where issue.iclientid = client.iclientid 
            and issue.istatusid <> 2 
        order by status.nrank desc, priorty.nrank desc, isstype.nrank desc) 
as cistypdesc,
    (select top 1 status.cstatdesc 
        from issue 
            inner join status on issue.istatusid = status.istatusid 
            left outer join priorty on issue.ipriortyid = priorty.ipriortyid 
            left outer join isstype on issue.iisstypeid = isstype.iisstypeid 
        where issue.iclientid = client.iclientid 
            and issue.istatusid <> 2 
        order by status.nrank desc, priorty.nrank desc, isstype.nrank desc) 
as cstatdesc,
    (select top 1 priorty.cpriority 
        from issue 
            inner join status on issue.istatusid = status.istatusid 
            left outer join priorty on issue.ipriortyid = priorty.ipriortyid 
            left outer join isstype on issue.iisstypeid = isstype.iisstypeid 
        where issue.iclientid = client.iclientid 
            and issue.istatusid <> 2 
        order by status.nrank desc, priorty.nrank desc, isstype.nrank desc) 
as cpriority,cname,ccity,cstateid,czip,isupplvlid 
from client 
where client.ccity like 'sea%' and client.isupplvlid <> 4
```

When I run this, I get the following errors:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
Invalid column name 'ccity'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
Invalid column name 'ccity'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
Invalid column name 'cstateid'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
Invalid column name 'czip'.
```

I can remove the references to ccity, cstateid, and czip to get it to execute without errors, but I get many more rows than I want, and not all of the information I need.

A helpful answer would show what I need to do to get this to work again now that I have a dbo.address table (that matches off of address.iclientid = client.iclientid. What would help more is to explain what needs to be done, so I can do it myself.

I can see that each of the inner selects are getting a piece of information from a specific table. I also know that INNER JOIN returns only data from columns that match, while LEFT OUTER JOIN returns all columns from the left table that match the right column. However, when these start to stack up, I'm not sure how they interact. Plus, when I took out the "where client.ccity like 'sea%'", I got thousands of rows rather than 4. If I add another of the commands in parenthesis, will this limit it back down to 4 again?

This SQL statement is just a little over my basic understanding.

Comment: do those columns exist in the client table?

Comment: @Randy: The ccity, cstate, and czip no longer exist there, and I realize that is why the error is happening. I'm just not quite sure how to redirect the query to look in the dbo.address table for them.

Comment: @Tim You will have to join `client` to `address` in the bottom part. If this needs to be a inner or outer join, I am not sure, but assuming there is a 1:1 relationship it would be an inner join. Then you can get the missing fields from that table instead of from `client` directly.

Comment: You would join to the address table (and you can probably use a join to remove all those verbose TOP 1 subqueries in the select list, too). Can you explain how client and address are related? Does client have an addressID? What if a client has two addresses, which one do you want?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: The address table has an iclientid that relates back to the client. Each client will have only one address. This is why we are adding sites, so there can be multiple accounts associated with a single client.

Comment: Doesn't the level of duplication in your query ring alarm bells for you? Replace the subqueries with a join.

Comment: @usr: I believe the duplication is due to the statement being built using several if statements depending on what criteria are being used in the search. I don't understand the commands enough currently to modify it any more than I need to. I hope to spend time increasing my skills in my off-time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join `client` to `address` so that you get the information from both tables that used to occur in just one table. Example:

```
FROM dbo.client AS c 
INNER JOIN dbo.address AS a
ON a.iclientid = c.iclientid
WHERE a.ccity LIKE 'sea%' ...
```

You also should look into removing all of those `TOP (1)` subqueries in the `SELECT` list - that can be facilitated with a simple join too, I suspect; but possibly an outer join, because I'm not sure if there isn't a 1:0 mapping there. Perhaps:

```
SELECT
  c.iclientid,
  x.cistypdesc,
  x.cstatdesc,
  x.cpriority,
  c.cname,
  a.ccity,
  a.cstateid,
  a.czip,
  c.isupplvlid 
FROM dbo.client AS c
INNER JOIN dbo.address AS a
ON c.iclientid = a.iclientid
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT iclientid, cistypdesc, cstatdesc, cpriority 
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT i.iclientid, i.cistypdesc, s.cstatdesc, p.cpriority,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.iclientid
         ORDER BY s.nrank DESC, p.nrank DESC, t.nrank DESC) 
     FROM dbo.issue
     INNER dbo.[status] AS s ON i.istatusid = s.istatusid 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.priorty AS p ON i.ipriortyid = p.ipriortyid 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.isstype AS t ON i.iisstypeid = t.iisstypeid 
     WHERE i.istatusid <> 2 
  ) AS y WHERE rn = 1
) AS x 
ON x.iclientid = c.iclientid
WHERE a.ccity LIKE 'sea%' AND c.isupplvlid <> 4;
```